# Background image in html template isn't displayed

Tags: html, css, web

The problem is that the html template in a message (Gmail) doesn't display the background image.
Here is the code(There should be some text instead of **):
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="ru">
<head></head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<style type = "text/css">
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;   
  height: 30px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.lower {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Minimalism-5.jpg');
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;

}

ul{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>

<body>
    <title>Document</title>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="lower">Приглашение на бета-тест!</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>


    </div>
      
</body>

</HTML>
```

`
What should I do to correct it?

I tried changing size of the background image, however it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try inline css style instead using in **body{}** 
try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="ru">
<head></head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<style type = "text/css">
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;   
  height: 30px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.lower {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}

body {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;

}

ul{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>

<body style="background-image: url('https://photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Minimalism-5.jpg');">
    <title>Document</title>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="lower">Приглашение на бета-тест!</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
            <li>********************</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>
        <div class="lower">********************</div>


    </div>
      
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks, but apparently it doesn't work

Comment: best way to use <table> structure for email templates. refer this
https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template/blob/master/email.html